# Low level HDD access

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Many years ago I used Runtime Software's DiskExplorer (a low level disk editor) on a FAT system and it worked fine. I recently tested their NTFS version but it wouldn't allow me to write to the HDD. I contacted the company and they told me it may be an inherent Windows security issue but they couldn't suggest a solution.

Can anyone here suggest a solution?

Comment: In Vista and later direct writes are not permitted to a partition hosting an NTFS file system. NTFS really doesn't like this.

Comment: A Linux live disk? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Attie - I just want to be able to do it, not for any particular reason, just to tinker around

Answer (score 0):

You may try Winhex at http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/index-m.html 
But unfortunately the evaluation version is read-only.